# how different between create ANN using a matrix multiplication and tf.layers.dense() in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I tried to train the ANN model using the matrix multiplication and tf.layers.dense(). But I got diferent result , ANN model using the matrix multiplication it can not optimize the loss function (loss increase). how different between two method ?

ANN model using the matrix multiplication

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,64]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64,64]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64,64]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
y3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y2, W3) + b3)

W4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64,3]))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))
y_out = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y3, W4) + b4)
```

ANN model using tf.layers.dense()

```
layer1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layer3 = tf.layers.dense(layer2, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layer4 = tf.layers.dense(layer3, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layer5 = tf.layers.dense(layer4, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layer6 = tf.layers.dense(layer5, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
y_out = tf.layers.dense(layer6, 3 , activation = tf.nn.softmax)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing the weights with zeros, which effectively prevents the network from learning anything as the network always outputs zero, and the gradient is always zero.

Initialize your weights with random values, like uniform or gaussian distribution with a small range (less than 0.1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is function tf.layers.dense() initialize weights with random at default ?